# Shorthand Notation on an Overrideable Property in VB.Net Not Working

Tags: vb.net, class, oop

In my VB.Net code, I know that when I declare a property in a class I can do so using the shorthand of, for example, `Public Property Prop1 As String` and .Net automatically creates a private variable `_Prop1` that I can refer to within my class.

I also know that I can refer to that variable within my code using either `_Prop1` or by `Prop1`.

Now since I've always assumed that the preferred method is to use the private variable, I've always tried to make modifications / write code within my class referring to `_Prop1`. This is where my problem now comes in...

I have the following situation:

```
Public Class MyClass_Base
   Public Overridable Property Prop1 As String = "val1"

   Public Sub Test()
       If _Prop1 = ....
   End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyClass
   Inherits MyClass_Base

   Public Overrides Property Prop1 As String = "val2"
End Class
```

Basically, I define the property as **Overridable** in my base class, now when I get to the `Test()` subroutine, `_Prop1` has the value of `Nothing`. However `Prop1` has the correct value of `val2`.

Programming gurus out there, what is the correct way to deal with this situation?
Do I ignore the auto-created prive variable `_Prop1` and work with the public `Prop1` or is there something else I should add in / not even use the shorthand notation for this and write my own getter / setter logic to ensure things change as I would like?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question.  You should absolutely not rely on hidden compiler mechanics in your own code.  You're referencing a variable that you did not declare and there is no guarantee in the framework that this variable will be there (or work as you might expect, as you've discovered) - it's a hack to use it, so don't.

Unless you have a very good reason not to, code in the class should reference the public property just the same as code using the class would.  If you're using automatic properties then there is no difference between doing that and using the private variable.  It also has the benefit that if you do, at a later time, decide to implement explicit getters and setters that your code does not break and that your new getters and setters get called.

To explore the reason you get the unexpected result, in declaring

```
  Public Overrides Property Prop1 As String = "val2"
```

You end up with two different `_Prop1` variables - `MyClass_Base._Prop1` and `MyClass._Prop1`.  When you then call `Test()`, you are calling the base class method and that will refer to the base class's `_Prop1` variable which has not been set to anything since you have overriden the implicit variable, getter, and setter in the subclass.

To illustrate the point, this is similar to :

```
Public Class MyClass_Base
    Private _Prop1 As String = "val1"

    Public Sub Test()
        Console.WriteLine(_Prop1)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MySubClass
    Inherits MyClass_Base
    Private _Prop1 As String = "val2"
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim class1 As New MyClass_Base
    Dim class2 As New MySubClass
    class1.Test()
    class2.Test()
End Sub
```

Where your output will be :

```
 val1
 val1
```

In the above case `MyClass_Base._Prop1` is always initialized, however, while in your case, it is not.  In either case, the `Test()` method belongs to the base class so it will always refer to its own `_Prop1` and not any variables of the same name declared in subclasses.

If you do need to refer to the private field, for whatever reason, you have to be very careful about how you do it (and the implications that follow).  Any method that does so would need to itself be `Overridable` if subclasses are intended to work with their own private variables in the same way.  Not to suggest that you should continue to use implicit variables, but to demonstrate :

```
Public Class MyClass_Base
    Public Overridable Property Prop1 As String = "val1"

    Public Overridable Sub Test()
        Console.WriteLine(_Prop1)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MySubClass
    Inherits MyClass_Base
    Public Overrides Property Prop1 As String = "val2"
    Public Overrides Sub Test()
        Console.WriteLine(_Prop1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here we get the "expected" result because `MySubClass` overrides test to reference its own private field.  Better to just stick to using the property names.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation on Auto Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx):

> *"Attributes specified for the property do not apply to the backing field."*

This is one of those areas where C# and VB.NET need to be aligned.

C# (correctly) does not allow you to access the auto implemented property backing field (without some convoluted work). I honestly don't know what you can access this in VB.

So the rule here is even though you can access the backing field of an auto implemented property you really shouldn't modify this directly (nor should you need to)

If you need to then you should use a defined backing field (with initialisation) and explicit `Get` and `Set`